# cannot connect subclipse to VisualSVN on Windows 7

Tags: subclipse, visualsvn-server, java-6, windows64

svn: connection refused by the server
svn: OPTIONS request failed on '/svn/myrepo/MyProject/trunk'
    svn: connection refused by the server

Java 32 bit 1.6.20
Windows 7 64 bit
Eclipse 3.5.2 32 bit
VisualSVN 2.1.3

Installed subclipse in Eclipse 3.5.2. Created repository myrepo and Project Structure MyProject.
Tried to open repository location https://desktop-PC/svn/myrepo/MyProject/trunk from subclipse and got error popup 
Error validating location org.tigris.subversion.javahl.ClientException: 
svn: connection refused by the server
svn: OPTIONS request failed on '/svn/myrepo/MyProject/trunk' ""

from a command prompt, I do the following: (I inserted a space in the server url on this post because stackoverflow only permits one hyperlink on a post).

ping https: //desktop-PC
Ping request could not find host https: //desktop-PC. Please check the name and
try again.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using raw IP addresses instead of names? This look more like a DNS resolving issue, not Java issue.

Answer (score 2):

If the repository is on the same machine, shouldn't you be using localhost as the server name?

Also you seem to be using https. That implies that there should be a http server running on your machine, and that your DNS is set to resolve your loopback address to the domain name desktop-PC. Are you sure you have a server running on your machine, and that the DNS is properly configured?

Comment: I have a desktop, Wifi router and laptop. I installed VisualSVN server and a repository on the desktop so that I could write code on the desktop, or laptop, and commit to the repository. This will allow me to get code to the laptop, go somewhere and work, come back home to the Wifi network and commit changes to the repository.
I dont know if more is needed for my setup?